# How to block caller thread after await operator

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

I'm using new HttpClient class to upload some data to the server, so I was forced to use new  operators like await/async.  I have following issue: how can I block a caller thread to wait until first file will be uploaded and after that move to the next one.

```
    public async Task Upload(string filename)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage();

        StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open));
        message.Method = HttpMethod.Put;
        message.Content = streamContent;
        message.RequestUri = new Uri(webURI);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(message);

        //I want to reach this point untill I will start to upload next file
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //do something
        }


    }

    void uploadFiles()
    {
        foreach (string filename in filenames)
        {
            Upload(filename);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any attention about my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` that the upload has finished before you upload the next file:

```
async void uploadFiles()
{
    foreach (string filename in filenames)
    {
        await Upload(filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for. So if for example I have such methods - UploadFolder() which call UploadFiles() and finally this routine call Upload() I need to add async/await operators to UploadFolder() and UploadFiles() as well?

Comment: If you want to find out when all uploads have finished, change `async void uploadFiles()` to `async Task uploadFiles()`, and then `await uploadFiles();`.